Does it count as auxiliary space if I overwrite the input-array?
Here is an example of what I mean:
// input = [1,5,5,9,6,5]
input = set(input)

Would overwriting the input in such a way count as O(1) or O(n) auxiliary space? And by extension, should you treat all input as read-only (meaning you'd need to make a copy of input to turn into a set?) unless specified that it is an in-place algorithm?

Assuming you are referring to Python code, set(input) would take additional space. Thus, it does not count as constant-space operation. Additionally, you are not modifying the input array. You are simply replacing the reference held by the variable input.

The input does not count as auxiliary space since the latter is extra space generated as part of the computation. If you only overwrite your array without creating any extra structure that is not constant in size, then your space complexity is $\mathcal{O}(1)$, i.e. constant.
